# 5 подряд идущих одинаковых по диагонали

Tags: c#

Привет есть двумерный массив

```
string[,] Array = new string[9,9];
```

Необходимо найти более 5 одинаковых символов на диагонали.

Comment: с чем возникли затруднения?

Comment: По какой диагонали?

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю, если была бы побочная, то было бы так и написано. Хотя...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я могу разделить квадрат 9*9 на кучу накладывающихся квадратов 5*5 и в каждом из них будет по 2 диагонали :D

Comment: @Qwertiy судя по описанию вопроса ТС - имелось в виду не такое извращение :))

Answer (score 2):

Для данного действия достаточно двух шагов:

- Первый: нужно пройтись по массиву и занести все числа с диагонали в массив.
- Второй: отфильтровать данные по условию "более 5 одинаковых"

**Итак, шаг № 1:**

Посмотрим три массива:

```
var matrix2D = [
  1, 2, 
  3, 4
];

var matrix3D = [
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9
];

var matrix4D = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5, 6, 7, 8, 
  9, 10, 11, 12,
  13, 14, 15, 16
];
```

Если внимательно посмотреть, то можно увидеть логику, по которой располагаются цифры на диагонали: номер строки и номер столбца совпадают. Зная это не сложно составить два цикла со счетчиками `i` и `j`, и в случае их совпадения заносить цифру в дополнительный массив (назовем его `arr2`).

**Шаг № 2:**

На этом шаге нужно посчитать количество вхождений чисел и отфильтровать по условию. Как это сделать? Способов уйма:

1. Один способ: использовать **[LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)**, выбрав из массива как раз те номера, количество которых больше 5. Для выборки можно будет воспользоваться `GroupBy` - для группировки значений, `Where` - для фильтрация по условию (> 5)) и `Select` для самой выборки. Все методы можно посмотреть в **[Документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)**
2. Еще способ: завести словарь (Dictionary), где ключом будет число, а значением - количество повторений этого числа. Затем сделать цикл, и на итерации проверять:

   - Нет такого ключа? Тогда заносим его в словарь и ставим счетчик в 0.
   - Есть такой ключ? Тогда увеличиваем счетчик в значении на 1

В итоге получив желаемый результат.

3. Другой способ: придумать самому))

Выбираешь способ и считаешь...

---

Happy End.